# Assign a divs id to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built rock paper scissors to run in a terminal/console window using prompts and alerts. I am now in the process of converting the game into something that is playable in a web browser with the use of the jQuery library.

To accomplish this I have made images of each of the hands: Rock paper & scissors. Now, I want a user to click on one of the hands and assign that move to a variable named *move*. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="grow pic">
      <img src="rock.png" class=id="rock" alt="rock" height="75" width="75">
    </div>

    <div class="grow pic">
      <img src="paper.png" id="paper" alt="paper" height="75" width="75">
    </div>
    <div class="grow pic">
      <img src="scissor.png" id="scissors" alt="scissors" height="75" width="75">
    </div>
```

And the jQuery I'm trying to implement:

```
  var move;
  $( "#id" ).click(function() {
  move = $(this).attr('id');
  });
```

So the question here, is how exactly do I make the id of an image assign to a variable named *move*. I keep getting an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: move is not defined(…)".

Comment: Where do you use `move`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
$( "#id" ).click(function() {
```

It attempts to select an element with the ID value 'id'. Instead, target images that are descendants of elements with a common class:

```
$('.pic img').click(function() {
```

Now your function should work as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this like:

```js
$("div img").click(function(){
    var move = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var move;
$( ".id" ).click(function() {
move = $(this).attr('id');
$('#result').html(move);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grow pic">
<img src="rock.png" class=id id="rock" alt="rock" height="75" width="75">
</div>

<div class="grow pic">
<img src="paper.png" class=id id="paper" alt="paper" height="75" width="75">
</div>

<div class="grow pic">
<img src="scissor.png" class=id id="scissors" alt="scissors" height="75" width="75">
</div>

<div id=result></div>
```

Run the click event against the class

Answer (score -1):

try

```
var move = document.getElementsByTagName(this).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem.